# Steinberg relations for elementary subgroup of a Chevalley group over an arbitrary ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, chevalley-groups

Given a semisimple Lie algebra $\frak{g}$ of type $\Phi$ with a Lie algebra representation $\rho:\frak{g}\to \frak{gl}(v)$ and an arbitrary commutative ring one can associate the following gadgets:

- A simply connected split reductive group scheme $G(\Phi)$ over $R$.
- An abstract group $G(\Phi,R)$ which is the $R$-points of the reductive group scheme $G(\Phi)$ which comes with an action on $V\otimes_\mathbb{Z}R$ (where $V$ is an appropriate $\mathbb{Z}$ lattice inside of $\frak{v}$ corresponding to some Chevalley basis).
- An abstract subgroup $E(\Phi,R)\leq G(\Phi,R)$ which is the subgroup generated by the root groups, that is, generated by elements of the form $U_\alpha(R)$ where $\alpha\in \Phi$ and $U_\alpha$ the root group associated to $\alpha$.

Whenever $R=k$ is a field one can also think of $E(\Phi,k)$ as an abstract group presented by symbols $x_\alpha(r)$ with $\alpha\in \Phi$ and $r\in R$ subject to the so called "Steinberg Relations". This is Corollary 3 on page 21 of this [pdf.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c4b8/389fde1252f59fdb4374630ef098296404f9.pdf)

For arbitrary rings $R$ the group $E(\Phi,R)$ will also satisfy the Steinberg relations and my question is wether or not those relations are sufficient to present $E(\Phi,R)$.

One approach to address this question is of course to follow this reference and verify that the hypothesis of $R$ being a field was not used on the process of proving Corollary 3. Skimming through the argument it seems quite possible to me, but since I want to use this result it would be very useful to me if there is already a reference that deals with this explicitly for arbitrary ring $R$, so that I do not have to repeat the argument as an appendix.

Comment: It seems you are asking if $K_2(\Phi,R)$ is always generated by Steinberg symbols. Definitely not.

Comment: The answer is no, for example for $\Phi = A_1$ and polynomial ring $R = \mathbb{Z}[T]$. (I think this is due to P. M. Cohn.)

Comment: It might help to point out that Steinberg's mimeographed lecture notes were distributed for many yeers by the Yae mathematics department, but a typeset and slightly revised set of notes was published after Steinberg's death by the AMS as part of their University Lecture Series

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the claim about $V$.  Do we start working over $\mathbb C$, or something less (any field?  Algebraically closed?  Characteristic 0?)?  Is the claim that *any* $\mathfrak v$ carries a canonical such lattice $V$ (corresponding somehow to a choice of Chevalley basis for $G(\Phi)$?), or are you only considering certain 'natural' representations, say the ones on classical groups that arise by considering them as fixed points of involutions?

Comment: Corollary 3 does not, indeed, use the assumption that the base ring is a field, but the preceding Proposition definitely does (in statement (b), which fails dramatically in general setting).

Comment: I am not very familiar with this area, but it looks to me like Chapter 6 of the notes you linked exactly addresses the question of what relations need to be added to the relations (R) in order to work for a general $k$-algebra.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your replies! I guess I was hoping there would be a universal way of presenting the abstract group of elementary matrices $E(\Phi,R)$ that is independent of the ring $R$. But from you answers I gather it might not be possible or at least that Steinberg's relations would usually not be sufficient.